# default directory for root in vsftpd on nginx server

Tags: linux, nginx, ubuntu-14.04

I want to change default directory when root user login via ftp.

At present I am getting root directory but i want to set it as

/usr/share/nginx/html

I am on nginx server with ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

Change the env. variable `HOME` from `.profile` file with the updated directory path.

Comment: Usually it will be in your current home directory.

Comment: `cd; ls -al` will list all the files from your home directory.

Comment: This is my .profile file. there is no HOME variable 


~/.profile: executed by Bourne-compatible login shells.


if [ "$BASH" ]; then
  if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
  fi
fi

mesg n

Comment: Do you mean `HOME `is defined in `.bashrc` file?

Comment: I can't find HOME neither in .profile nor in .bashrc file

Comment: `grep HOME .*` it should show the file where we set the HOME env variable

Comment: I see another solution as 

usermod -m -d /path/to/new/home/dir root But it shows error

usermod: user root is currently used by process 1